# C++ stream object's initialization and connecting it to input/output consoles/sources

Tags: c++, io

I was studying I/O from https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp10_IO.html which says:

> To perform input and output, a C++ program:
>
> 1: Construct a stream object.
>
> 2: Connect (Associate) the stream object to an actual IO device (e.g., keyboard, console, file, network, another program).

Now to try this I created a basic program:

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::streambuf *obj;  
    obj=cin.rdbuf();
    std::istream s_obj(obj);
    s_obj>>i;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to create something on my own which is same as `cin/cout` and the above program works fine. I wanted to understand:

1. I have not connected the stream object `s_obj` to any **IO** device instead it is connected to `istream`'s buffer even then I can supply input correctly - How? How is buffer managing to get input from console - Do I need to worry about it?
2. If I assign `cin`'s buffer directly to the `s_obj` it gives an error (which I can't understand very well as I am a newbie to C++) but if it is done either like it has been done in above example or like `std::istream s_obj(cin.rdbuf())` it works fine - what's the difference as even while initializing other variables direct-initialization and copy-initialization both work fine.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wanted to create an `istream` object and make it read till `EOF` is encountered - this was the first step where I simply read an input - already I have a lot of questions and there are so many classes involved in I/O which make things confusing.

Comment: `std::streambuf` is what really represents the underlying device. `istream` provides services like formatted input (e.g an ability to read a sequence of digit characters and interpret them as an `int`) to the raw stream of characters coming from `streambuf`. `std::cin` is initially set up with a `streambuf` hooked up to standard input stream. You created another `istream` object wrapping the same `streambuf`, and thus also reading from the standard input stream.